# Raspberry Pi errors on VNC login and ssh startup

Tags: bash, terminal, raspberry-pi

For some weird reason, this two errors started occurring on ssh connection initiation:

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

I'm not sure how those errors affect me, but in the last few days my VNC connection to raspberry pi also stopped working (I can see the login screen in the VNC viewer, but after i put my credentials, the screen turns black for a moment and then returns to the same login screen which I'm stuck on...)

I've tried updating my pi version through ssh and use some other commands I've found online, but nothing worked. Any idea how to solve those problems?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is trying to load on login.

The places to check are as follows:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
```

`~/.profile` gets ran each time you login to the shell and the others run when running the `bash` shell.

By the looks of it something is trying to run the command `id` and as its not installed it's not running.

A quick test to see if this is in any of your files would to run `grep` in your home area.

```sh
# Change to your home area
cd ~/
# Recursively search for a string matching "id"
grep -rsi "id" .
```

This could explain why `VNC` is not working, as when you try to login to `VNC` it tries to load your config from those files and if they error `VNC` might not launch.